# Line & Clustered Column Chart

Tags: excel, powerbi

Curently I have a Line & Clustered Column. Is there a  way to make the line and bar chart a line in line chart? I want to have a line chart with both an x and a y axis.

Comment: Isn't a line chart with multiple values what you want?

Comment: Yest but I want have two separate Axis's. Saw Cost and kWh.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does not have a built-in chart that does that.

Comment: Is there a way to make one?

Comment: Yes there is.  Power BI provides the ability for people to add custom visualizations. You can get started on http://www.github.com/Microsoft/PowerBi-visuals repo.  There are helpful videos on the Power BI YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1N57mwBHtN12K0rY9QkqAX4OUqw7azi8

Comment: Can I grab one of the visualizations from here http://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/playground/index.html to edit it in https://app.powerbi.com/devTools?

Comment: Does Microsoft have any starter code that I can edit to try to get this, or will I have to write it all myself?